# how to create a pre-defined process in latex tikz

Tags: latex, flowchart, tikz

I don't know what to call this block in latex, it must be done somehow with arrows, please help.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, you just have to write it:

> 1. \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}
>    \usepackage{tikz}
>    \usepackage{flowchart} %special library%

> 2. \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes,shapes.multipart, shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

> 3. \node (predproc2) [draw, predproc, align=left, text centered,
>    minimum height=1cm, below=of dec2 %enter your name%] {text%your name%};
> 4. [image: result]